# Cómo calcular la edad al momento de su contratación en un empleo MySql

Tags: mysql

Necesito mostrar el código, nombre, apellido, fecha de contratación, fecha de nacimiento, **y edad que tenían al momento de su contratación de todos los empleados** aquí es donde tengo el problema me trae una edad incorrecta.

La sintaxis en MySql es:

```
Select EmployeeID,
    FirstName,
    LastName, 
    HireDate, 
    BirthDate, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,HireDate,CURDATE()) AS edad 
    from employees;
```

Por ello pido de su apoyo en este caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con esa consulta estas calculando cuantos años lleva contratado, porque restas fecha actual con fecha de contratación. Lo que quieres calcular es la diferencia en años entre fecha de contratación y fecha de nacimiento.

Tu consulta debería ser:

```
Select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate, BirthDate,
```

**TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate, HireDate)**

```
AS edad from employees;
```

Ya que sería la diferencia en años desde que nació hasta que fue contratado